# Pair of 3-way switches, when one is on, the other won't toggle it

Tags: electrical, wiring, lighting, multiway-switch

I have a pair of 3-way switches. I've wired them the same way as the other 4 in the same box (as far as I can tell), but they're not working as expected. I've tried re-wiring them each lots of various ways, but can never get them both to work as expected at the same time. I can get one to work, but the other doesn't. Or visa versa.

At the moment, I have it so that there is only one combination of up/down that will cause the light to be off.

[image: four scenarios]

Photo of the left set:

[image: photo]

Answer (score 1):

You need to wire them properly for them to work properly.

So, the unswitched hot needs to go to the black screw on one switch. The switched hot to the light needs to go to the black screw on the other switch. The travelers between the switches need to be on the brass screws on both switches.

Comment: "You need to wire them properly for them to work properly." - I figured out that part! :)  Really don't follow what you're saying for the rest. This one is wired just like the rest. Should it be different? Or can you provide clarification on what you think I did wrong? Unfortunately, I am currently out of ideas on "wiring them properly", as I thought I did that in the first place.

Comment: If the wires to the switches are not wired "the same as the rest" in the rest of the circuit that you have not shown, then they won't work "the same as the rest" either. Sort out which wire is the unswitched hot. Sort out which wire is connected to the lights. Blindly following "the colors are the same" only works if everything else is consistently the same. Apply a meter, and figure out what's actually connected to what here (which might involve looking at the other switch box and the junction box where the light is.)

Comment: *"Really don't follow what you're saying for the rest"*  How do you expect to be successful, then??? You can't make wiring work if you don't understand it.  Electrical wiring is not complicated, *but it's too complicated to google*.   It's time to either "hit the books", or call a professional.  It's easy to create very dangerous situations in electricity.